# titanium-extension Error processing "launch": Unable to find running task in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, task, appcelerator-titanium, launch

I have an application that was developed using Titanium appcelerator (I know it was descontinued, but rigth now I don't have time to rewite the app in an other language) using the Visual Studio Code with the titanium plugin.

Recently I was able to run the app to my device and launch the app to Xcode organizer.

But after an update (I don't know what updated), I'm no longer able to test my app on my device. I get a pop-up message with this:

```
[titanium-extension] Error processing "launch": Unable to find running task
```

And in the console I get this error:

```
Error running task
Unable to find loaded project for /Users/manuelrodrigues/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/aqua-info, please ensure it is active in the workspace
```

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch on Android",
        "type": "titanium",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch on iOS",
        "type": "titanium",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "ios"
    }
]
```

}

Instaled versions:

node: v17.7.1
npm: 8.5.2
vscode: 1.65.2 (Universal)
appcelerator titanium plugin: 0.14.0
appcelerator titanium SDK: 10.1.1.GA

Can anyone help me with this error? I really don't know what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node 17 is currently not supported. The maximum version is 16 (it will log a warning but works fine). So I would downgrade your node and then reinstall the toolchain with `sudo npm i -g titanium alloy` and start vscode again.

You can always use the CLI too `ti build -p ios -C foo` and compile it this way.

Quick side note: it is not discontinued, it's just a completly open-source project now and Tidev Inc. will continue to maintain the work. More updates will come and all modules will be updated and its still maintained!

Comment: Hi, THANK YOU SO MUCH. You saved my day. Just a little question, the new updates will they be installed automatically or do I need to do something?

Comment: same as before: `ti sdk install latest` or wait for a notification in VSCode. Check https://tidev.io/ for Twitter or Slack to stay up to date for news